# How many arguments does the map function take in SML?

Tags: functional-programming, sml, ml

I'm trying to learn SML and some of my professor notes talk about the `map` function "which has type ('a -> 'b) -> ('a list -> 'b list)."  He goes on to explain that this means that "you give me a function that transforms 'a s into 'b s...".

However, he the implementation looks like:

```
fun map f [] = []
  | map f (a::l) = (f a)::(map f l)
```

This appears to me that it's taking the equivalent of 2 arguments (I know that everything in sml technically only takes one argument, but using tuples or currying it can look like 2).  It appears that it's taking a function and a list.  However, the explanation above makes it sound like it's only taking a function.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said yourself SML doesn't really have polyadic functions, it only simulates using tuples or currying. In this case `map` is a curried function. The reason that your professors statement makes sense is that a curried function is simply a function that takes one argument and returns a function that takes the next argument.

One way to see this is to rewrite `fun` in terms of `val`. In general `fun f x y = bla` is equivalent to `val rec f = fn x => fn y => bla`. So the definition of `map` can equivalently be written like this:

```
val rec map = fn f => fn as => case as of
    [] => []
  | (a::l) => (f a)::(map f l)
```

Looking at that definition it's clear that the first `fn` creates a function that returns another function (the second `fn`).

We can also see that this is the case by observing that it is legal to call `map` with only one argument and the result is a function:

```
val my_map = map my_function
val mapped_list = my_map my_list
```

In the above `my_map my_list` is equivalent to `map my_function my_list`. This shows us that calling `map my_function my_list` (which is equivalent to `(map my_function) my_list` due to function application being left-associative) simply calls `map` with the argument `my_function` and then calls the function retuned by `map` with `my_list` as its argument.

That's what currying is all about.